# Access symbol key of array of one hash value?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Is there a better, faster, and more direct way to access the symbol key of `:a2` in this array of one hash `[{:a2=>nil}]`?

I have tried `@new_array.first.first.first` and `@new_array.first.keys.first`.

Comment: If you're after that `nil` then `a[0][:a2]` or `a.first[:a2]` would be common.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant symbol key and edited my question.

Comment: Then `@new_array.first.keys.first` is probably as good as it gets unless you prefer `[0]` over `first`: `@new_array[0].keys[0]`.

Comment: thank you mu is too short.  I can also check your answer if you write it in below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `@new_array.first.keys.first`, but this is assuming you always want the first key of the first hash.

Comment: Or any other way that give you the first element: @new_array[0].keys[0]